# When an assignment between a 2d-array [][] and an array [] is legit?

Tags: java

Let's suppose

```
Object[][]a; //a matrix of Objects
Exception[] r; //an array of Exceptions
```

*(note that Exception is subclass of Object)*

Now, when

```
a = r;
```

is legit in Java?

Comment: What do you think? And what does your compiler tell you?

Comment: [`a = r` is not valid](https://ideone.com/bE02SU).

Comment: > Exception[] cannot be converted to Object[][]

Comment: then not legit - any other questions?

Comment: Yes, but this happens in particular between Object[][] and Exception[]. What about other types? Is an assignment between [][] and [] always not legit?

Comment: Again: What do *you* think?

Comment: I downvoted because [no attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). This example would have taken you 2 minutes to try yourself.

Comment: @AustinSchäfer that was an example. The question is about a general behaviour

Comment: @user11594035 irrelevant; the general behavior can be proven with a compiled class and some logic.

Comment: [It's valid the other way around, however](https://ideone.com/W0c1aZ).

Comment: @MCEmperor this is due the upcasting, I suppose...

Comment: @user11594035 An `Object[]` is also an `Object`, because [an array is an object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1). This is why `Object[] a; Object[][] r; a = r;` works. The fact that the *component type* of `r` can also be `Exception`, is because [arrays are *covariant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C%23).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you'll need to assign it to a specific index in your 2d-array, and ensure your arrays are initialized to begin with:

```
Object[][] a = new Object[5][5];
Exception[] r = new Exception[5];
a[0] = r;
```

Since everything is a subclass of Object you'll be able to store anything in the 2d-array as long as the dimensions of the assignment match. This means you'll be able to do:

```
a = r                    => if r is a 2d array as well
a[index] = r             => if r is a 1d array
a[index-1][index-2] = r  => if r is any type extending Object
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java arrays are type of objects. So you can do:

```
Object a = null;
Object[][][] b = null;

a = b;
```

which also allows:

```
Object a[] = null;
Object[][][][] b = null;

a = b
```

But you cannot ever do it the other way around.